# With reddit's api how do you download a selected thread?

Tags: python-3.x

How would you go about downloading all the comments in the thread below?

The reddit thread:
[What do you personally view as a scam that everyone accepts otherwise?](https://old.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/cz6fi1/what_do_you_personally_view_as_a_scam_that/?st=k0769dwg&sh=2dce6485)

I've been playing around with teh code I found on [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/scraping-reddit-data-1c0af3040768).

Anyone know of a good tutorial which would show me how to download all the the comments within a thread? Note I would like to know if a main comment or a reply to something else someone said.

```
import praw
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='xxxx', \
                     client_secret='xxxxx', \
                     username='xxxx', \
                     password='xxxxx', \
                     user_agent='xxxx')

posts = []
ml_subreddit = reddit.subreddit('AskReddit')
for post in ml_subreddit.hot(limit=10):
    posts.append([post.title, post.score, post.id, post.subreddit, post.url, post.num_comments, post.selftext, post.created])
posts = pd.DataFrame(posts,columns=['title', 'score', 'id', 'subreddit', 'url', 'num_comments', 'body', 'created'])
print(posts)
```

Comment: BTW, you don't need line continuations here.

Comment: From skimming the docs about [`praw.Reddit`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/reddit_instance.html), it looks like you would call `reddit.submission` then get `comments` from the returned [`Submission` object](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/submission.html#praw.models.Submission).

Answer (score 0):

First; the submission object.
`submission = reddit.submission(url='')`
or, if you have the id instead;
`submission = reddit.submission(id='')`

Next, the comments;
`top_level_comments = [x for x in submission.comments]`
or, if you get an attribute error;

```
from praw.models import MoreComments
top_level_comments = [x for x in submission.comments if isinstance(x, MoreComments)]
```

To get the body of a comment, say;
`comment.body`
With the comment object as;
`reddit.comment(id='')`

Answer (score 0):

I found out you have to hit the little run button for the block of code before you hit preview. That works for me.